# Meaning of 徹している in this sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, verbs, manga, sports

After watching a boxing match, a spectator says about the winner:

> 相手にボクシングをさせないように自分の全てを発揮してる…　勝つための〝確実さ〟に**徹している**

徹す seems to have so many meanings that I don't know how to interpret it here. First of all, is it [徹す]{とおす} or [徹する]{てっする}? If it's the latter, could it mean "to devote oneself", in the sense of doing just a specific thing? My attempt:

> He shows all he has to prevent the opponent from fighting... He
>   just uses his confidence to win.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「徹する」 is read 「てっする」 every time.

「勝{か}つための〝確実{かくじつ}さ〟に徹{てっ}している」 means "***He is devoting his entire attention to his ’assurance’ of a win***."